# matriz [l][c] The local Variable c may not have been initialized

Tags: java

bom dia, sou iniciante em java e estou estudando sobre matrizes, estou fazendo uma aplicação simples onde devo preencher uma matriz e depois somar seus elementos, porem estou tendo um erro na hora mostrar a matriz depois de preenchida. Abaixo segue o inicio do código

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class somaMatriz {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        int[][] mat = new int[5][5];
        int l,c,soma;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bem vindo ao software somaMatriz v_1.0");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inicializando a Matriz..");

        for (l=0; l<5; l++){
            for (c=0; c<5; c++){
               mat[l][c] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Entre com o valor da posição [" + l +"][" + c +"]"));       
            }//fim-para-c
        }//fim-para-l

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Matriz finalizada");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mat[l][c]);
    }
}
```

nessa ultima linha esta dando o erro "The local variable c may not have been initialized"

ja tentei na declaração inicializar com valor 0 e o erro continua

alguem poderia me explicar o porque?

Comment: Mas por que vc quer imprimir `mat[l][c]` fora do loop? Não faz sentido, porque depois que o `for` termina, o valor de `l` e `c` é `5`, então vc estará acessando uma posição inválida de `mat`.

Answer (score 0):

Para quem ver este post, consegui descobrir o problema

para mostrar a matriz em questao não basta apenas utilizar o comando

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mat[l][c]);
```

é preciso criar uma estrutura de repetição para poder pegar todos os valores da matriz e assim poder imprimir

meu código ficou assim

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class somaMatriz {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        int[][] mat = new int[5][5];
        int l,c,soma;
        String exibir = "";

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bem vindo ao software somaMatriz v_1.0");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inicializando a Matriz..");

        for (l=0; l<5; l++){
            for (c=0; c<5; c++){
               mat[l][c] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Entre com o valor da posição [" + l +"][" + c +"]"));       
            }//fim-para-c
        }//fim-para-l

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Matriz finalizada");
        for (l=0; l<5; l++){
            exibir += "[ ";
            for (c=0; c<4; c++){
                exibir += mat[l][c] + " | ";
            }//fim-para-c
            exibir += mat[l][c];
            exibir += " ]";
            exibir += "\n";
        }//fim-para-l
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, exibir);
        
    }
}
```